# typescript remove optional property

Tags: typescript, typescript3.0

I'm trying to build a dynamic type for a builder

```
export type Builder<T, K extends keyof T> = {
    [P in K]: (value: T[P]) => Builder<T, K>;
} & {
    build(): Readonly<T>;
};
```

If I have a class or an interface with optional properties, I get this kind of error:

```
$ tsc
test/OtherClass.ts:29:1 - error TS2722: Cannot invoke an object which is possibly 'undefined'.

29 OtherClass.builder().patate(Patate.AU_FOUR).build();
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

This is my class

```
export class OtherClass {
    constructor(
        public literal: string | undefined,
        public patate?: Patate,
        public hello: Readonly<Hello> = {},
    ) { }

    static builder: () => Builder<OtherClass, keyof OtherClass> = builder.for(OtherClass);
}
```

I was expecting the type to create a builder with a non-optional method for each properties, but for some reason, the optionality of `patate` seem inherent to the key and not the type. I don't get this behavior with the property `literal`

It looks like an issue to me. I'm using typescript 3.1.4. Is there another way to remove the question mark dynamically?

I've tried to use the `NonNullable` helper to create first a copy of my type with nothing nullable, but `patate` remains optional.

This is the effective type that vscode gives me

```
(property) patate?: ((value: Patate | undefined) => Builder<OtherClass, "literal" | "patate" | "hello">) | undefined
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Does this help?

```
export type Builder<T, K extends keyof T> = {
    [P in K]-?: (value: T[P]) => Builder<T, K>;
} & {
    build(): Readonly<T>;
};
```

Note the `-?` which does what you want - removes optionality.

Comment: Yes thanks, but do you know why it inherits the optionality from the key name?

Comment: When the "constraint" of a mapped type (the type after `in`, which determines the set of properties) is of the form `keyof T` or is a type parameter constrained by `keyof T` for some type `T`, the mapped type is "homomorphic" and copies modifiers (optional and readonly) from `T`.  There's a bit about this [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#mapped-types).